# max $\sin(x)/x$ without derivative

Tags: maxima-minima

Showing $max(\frac{sin(x)}{x})=1$ is straight forward using l'hopital's rule. Is there another way to evaluate without using l'hopital's rule

Comment: It is not straightforward, it is circular.

Comment: Do you mean Sup(sin x/x)?

Comment: It's pretty easy using the Taylor series, but there is some sense it which is, as DanielC calls l'Hopital's rule, circular.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

To prove that $\sup\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)=1$ we can proceed showing that

- $\frac{\sin x}x$ is even and not defined at $x=0$ then we can consider $x>0$
- $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}x=1$
- $g(x)=x-\sin x >0$ for $x>0$

Refer to the related

- [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/505767)